# Keeping track of user signed in to the page via Social Medias

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, twitter

I'm currently working on a login app for my site, it basically allows the user to log in via social medias (fb/twitter/google), or if the user doesn't have either of these create an account directly on the site.

When the user is logged in he/she will be able to create new posts (wordpress) in the frontend.

What I'm struggling with is keeping track of the user, the author should be tracked in a custom meta in the post itself, but this needs to be a unique ID for this user (For sorting archive purposes).

My original plan was to use the name and e-mail and connect those to the posts. But Twitter API doesn't give out the users e-mail. And without knowing the e-mail I can't connect a post to a certain user. Since two people may have the same name (if I were to use the name to keep track of the user for example.)

So either I prompt the user to fill in e-mail if they login via twitter (but this adds an extra step), or I just don't care if the user gets more accounts cause they didn't login with the same social media. But I'm not very fond of either solution.

Is there anyway I can keep track?

Comment: Facebook gives uniq ID for user, as I remember twitter too... Can't use that info?

Comment: The ID is different tho, FB has its own unique ID and so do twitter. Been doing som research and it would seem most sites that offers social media logins solves this by either not allowing the user to sign in via twitter, or prompting the user to type his email in aswell. I will prolly use the second solution for my project.